# Is it possible to write a program to break a random substitution cipher in python?

Tags: python, encryption

In short I want to write a program that can accept any substitution cipher and decrypt it into all every possible solution. So if you gave it a random string of letters it would be able to take that and return every possible variation of the layout of that string, in the sense that if two letters are the same in the "encrypted" string they'll "decrypt" to the same letters in all of the results. However, it HAS to work for nonlinear substitutions, e.g. a -> h, b -> f, c -> z, think of it like if you were to write a sentence and then choose random symbols to represent the letters, there's no way of knowing what the symbols represent but because there would be duplicates of them you can work it out based on their positioning. Does that sorta make sense? Is this something that is possible?

Comment: It's certainly possible, but as for solving non-linear cyphers, you'll need to read up on approaches to solving those. If the substitution is non-linear but constant then it should fall to frequency analysis if the cypher is long enough.

Comment: Every possible variation? By my calculations there are 25×23×21×19×17×15×13×11×9×7×5×3×1 = 7,905,853,580,625 of them. Are you only looking for ones that decrypt to English text?

Comment: @JohnKugelman, yeah, the brute force approach is not a great idea here, although 8 trillion is not that scary if you have a decent PC.

Comment: @pavel No 8 trillion is an insane number of keys to test for a problem that can be solved using much more efficient methods that have been around for literally hundreds of years. In any case, the number of keys is far larger: 26 factorial is about 400 septillion. Search for monoalphabetic cipher cryptanalysis for better methods.

Comment: @r3mainer, oh yeah definitely not suggesting it's a good idea to go brute force.